# Dynamically Update Page in Application Requiring Authentication Via Azure AD

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am curious if anyone has a solution to this unique situation as I have a solution currently, though I feel it is not the most optimal.

**The Situation.**
I have built an MVC style web application that talks to a web API through http (authenticating via JWT). My web application is secured by appending authorization to its view controllers and redirecting to a Microsoft login endpoint - then directing back to the view where whichever given controller/function handles the request, connects to the API, appends data to the view, etc.

Preferably I would like to use JQuery/Ajax to submit http requests client-side and update a given view with whatever data the user may wish to see relative to the webpage they're on. This way I could control exactly what the user should see landing on the page any which way and submitting requests from web app to API. Also would enable better continuity between requests as there isn't actually a full refresh of the view. All in all it is my line of thought that this execution would lead to a nice user experience.

**The Problem.**
So the big issue that I have had to circumvent is CORS Policy. I initially attempted to use JS just as I said above but requests would be redirected to the login endpoint and blocked due to there being no CORS header appended to the request.

'So include a policy in your application and append an authorized header to your Ajax outgoing request' you might say, well... you cannot override CORS security around Microsoft's login endpoint.

**My Solution.**
What I have done simply instead is create HTML Forms around fields the user would pick and chose to specify what data they wanted from the API. Then carry over input data to the returned view via 'ViewData'

and using razor pages of course I can actually initialize JS variables via C# input.

**Side Note**
I use JS to transform the API data into graphs for the user to see. I am doing this with a JavaScript Library.

**My Question to you.**
This all leads me to ask then, is there a way to dynamically update a view without using JS? I require a method that can hit the login redirect without being blocked because the request initiated client-side.

Every solution I am aware in some way, shape, or form utilizes JS to make the request. So I am at a loss for how to truly get the functionality I am after without having my requests get blocked due to CORS Policy.

Thanks in advance y'all.

Comment: Why not add cors support in your web api project?

Comment: There isn't a redirect to login endpoint for API. It uses a JWT Token for authentication. I cannot apply a CORS policy for the Microsoft login endpoint within the Web Application however, since according to their support, it cannot be applied when redirecting to that specific endpoint.